# Change color of edit box in runtime

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

How to change the background color of a edit box if user modifies its content in MFC.
How to change it in ON_EN_CHANGE MSg of a Edit control.

Comment: Handle WM_CTLCOLOR message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically your solution is

```
    HBRUSH CEditDialog::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
    {
              switch (nCtlColor) {

              case CTLCOLOR_EDIT:
              case CTLCOLOR_MSGBOX:
                  // Set color to green on black and return the background
                     brush.
                  pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 255, 0));
                  if(ChangeColor == TRUE)
                  {
                      pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
                      ChangeColor = FALSE;
                  }
                  return (HBRUSH)(m_pEditBkBrush->GetSafeHandle());

              default:
                  return CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);


}
```

}

Now you want textbox color change on text change then,

```
    ::OnEnchange()
{
   ChangeColor = TRUE;      //Its global flag maintain in any global position may be in your .H file.
}
```